# Angular 8 Http Observables in ngOnInit()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm still new to Angular and learning Angular 8 currently.

I'm trying to create a simple API communication Service to load the data needed for display. I have a main Component with a sub-Component and both need to fetch data to load.

I've tried following several tutorials but my common issue is that the Component loading is happening before the API HTTP request is returned, leading to undefined data.

My current API Service uses `HttpClient` to communicate with the API

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getUserFeed(id: number): Observable<Post[]> {
        return this.http
        .get<Post[]>(`${API_URL}/feed`)
        .pipe(
            retry(3),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
    }

    getProfile(id: number): Observable<Profile> {
        return this.http
        .get<Profile>(`${API_URL}/profile/${id}`)
        .pipe(
            retry(3),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
    }

    handleError(error: any) {
        let errorMessage: string;
        // Set error message
        (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) ?
            errorMessage = error.error.message :
            errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.code}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
        console.log(errorMessage);
        return throwError(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

The API should be returning an array of `Posts` I've defined.

I call this in my component as

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';
import { ApiService } from '../api/api.service';
import { User } from '../user';
import { Post } from '../Post';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-feed',
    templateUrl: './feed.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./feed.component.css'],
})
export class FeedComponent implements OnInit {
    posts: Post[] = [];
    user: User;
    post: Post;

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
        this.user = this.userService.user;
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.userService.getUserFeed(this.user.id).subscribe((feed) => {
            this.posts = feed;
            console.log(this.posts);
        });
    }
}
```

My Component HTML should loop through these posts and pass the post to the sub-Components I have

```html
<div *ngIf="posts.length">
    <mat-list *ngFor="let post of posts">
        <!-- Post Display -->
        <app-post-display [post]=post></app-post-display>

        <!-- Post Interaction Row -->
        <app-post-interaction-bar [post]=post></app-post-interaction-bar>

        <!-- Comment Preview -->
        <app-comment-preview [post]=post></app-comment-preview>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    </mat-list>
</div>
```

So far it seems to be picking up the posts for the main component as expected. The issue is in the sub-Component `app-post-display` which performs a similar action getting the post author from the `post.authorId` property.

I've declared an author and I've placed the code to fetch the author data in ngOnInit but I consistently get `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` in the console, no matter what I try it seems that the Component is trying to display before the author is fetched.

What do I need to adjust to have the author data fetched before the Component display is loaded

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';
import { User } from '../user';
import { Post } from '../post';
import { Profile } from '../profile';
import { ApiService } from '../api/api.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-post-display',
    templateUrl: './post-display.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./post-display.component.css'],
})
export class PostDisplayComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() post: Post;
    user: User;
    author: Profile;

    constructor(private userService: UserService, private backend: BackendService) {
        this.user = this.userService.user;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.backend.getProfile(this.post.authorId).subscribe((profile) => {
            this.author = profile;
            console.log(this.author);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I found for my problem was actually using a resolver before the page is directed to (https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve).

This allowed the data to be loaded before the page was fully rendered, hence no errors.

Answer (score 2):

`ngOnInit` of the Child Component will run only once. Also, you can't expect it to get the `post` defined initially.

To fix it, you should move your call to `ngOnChanges` and check if `post` is defined first. Here, give this a try:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';
import { User } from '../user';
import { Post } from '../post';
import { Profile } from '../profile';
import { ApiService } from '../api/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-display',
  templateUrl: './post-display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-display.component.css'],
})
export class PostDisplayComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() post: Post;
  user: User;
  author: Profile;

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService, 
    private backend: BackendService
  ) {
    this.user = this.userService.user;
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.post) {
      this.backend.getProfile(this.post.authorId).subscribe((profile) => {
        this.author = profile;
        console.log(this.author);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can do that in your Parent Component:

```
<div *ngIf="posts">
    <mat-list *ngFor="let post of posts">
        <!-- Post Display -->
        <app-post-display [post]=post></app-post-display>

        <!-- Post Interaction Row -->
        <app-post-interaction-bar [post]=post></app-post-interaction-bar>

        <!-- Comment Preview -->
        <app-comment-preview [post]=post></app-comment-preview>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    </mat-list>
</div>
```

Just make sure you're not initializing the `posts` with an empty array initially though.